# Remove @PathVariable from the Model

Tags: spring-mvc

In a @RequestMapping, when you grab a variable in the URL using @PathVariable, the variable itself is added to the Model which is then available in your view.

How can I ensure that the @PathVariable is not added to the Model automatically without going to the model and removing it every time?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the `PathVariable`? Doing so seems unnecessary.

Comment: I have a common controller which is extended by all my controllers. The common controller allocates common Variables to the Model.

In one of my controllers which is extending the common controller, I have a path variable which is named as one of the common variables. Now I only use the path variable in my Java code and I do not need it in the Model for my View. Moreover, due to standardization I do not want to change the name of both of these variables. Hence I wanted to know whether there is a way in which the path variable is not included in the Model, which will solve this problem.